# What means the definition of path and leaf array in jq --stream man page

Tags: man, array, json, jq

In the `jq` manual page, `--stream` option, says:

> Parse the input in streaming fashion, outputing arrays of path and
> leaf values (scalars and empty arrays or empty objects). For
> example, `"a"` becomes `[[],"a"]`, and `[[],"a",["b"]]` becomes `[[0],[]]`, `[[1],"a"]`, and `[[1,0],"b"]`.

I want to know the meaning of "arrays of path and leaf values" and why the input representation is transformed like:

```
"a" -> [[],"a"]
```

and

```
[[],"a",["b"]] ->  [[0],[]]  , [[1],"a"]  , [[1,0],"b"]
```

I have been reviewing trees like list representation but it's not similar.

Comment: It also seems as if `[[],"a",["b"]]` actually turn into `[[0],[]]`,
`[[1],"a"]`,
`[[2,0],"b"]`,
`[[2,0]]`,
`[[2]]` with `jq` 1.6 (the manual is wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid for `jq` release 1.6:

In stream mode, what you get is a series of arrays encoding the data in the input. Each array consists of an array encoding a path, and a value at that path (which is what I believe you call a "leaf value").  To denote the termination of an object or array in the stream, an array with no value is emitted.

For example, the JSON object `{"key":"value"}` would be streamed as the two arrays

```json
[["key"],"value"]
[["key"]]
```

The first stream array consists of a path and a value. The path is simply `["key"]` as that key is a top-level key.  The value at that path is `"value"`.

The second array only has the path and no value, denoting the end of that streamed object (there will be no further keys for that object in the output stream).

Another example:

The composite object

```json
{
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    {
      "hello": "world"
    }
  ]
}
```

would be streamed as

```json
[["array",0],1]
[["array",1],2]
[["array",2,"hello"],"world"]
[["array",2,"hello"]]
[["array",2]]
[["array"]]
```

The first array contains the path `["array",0]`, i.e. the first element of an array which is the value of the top-level key `array`.  The value at that path is `1`.

The second array contains the path `["array",1]`, i.e. the second element of the same array, and the value `2`.

The third array contains the path `["array",2,"hello"]`.  This path denotes the key `hello` at the third position of the array at the top-level key `array`.  The value at that path is `world`.

Then follows a set of three arrays with no values, each one signalling that the last part of `.array[2].hello`, `.array[2]`, and `.array` (respectively) has been streamed.

The manual for `jq` 1.6 uses the example `[0,[1]]`, which is streamed as the four arrays

```json
[[0],0]
[[1,0],1]
[[1,0]]
[[1]]
```

It's slightly difficult to see what's going on here since there's only the two integers `0` and `1` in the data, bet changing these into the strings `"a"` and `"b"`, we get

```json
[[0],"a"]
[[1,0],"b"]
[[1,0]]
[[1]]
```

Again, there are two arrays with paths and values, and then two arrays that terminate the sub-array that only contains `"b"`, and the top-level array.

Keeping this example shorter, the first array simply says there is a path, `[0]`, i.e. the top-level object must be an array, with a value `"a"` in the first position. The path `[1,0]` denotes the first element of  the second element of the top-level array, which has the value `"b"`.

To answer your explicit question about why `"a"` is streamed as `[[],"a"]`: The path `[]` denotes a thing that is not part of any other object or array.  The value at that path is `"a"`.  That is, you have an `"a"` that is not part of an object nor array.